# keras resetting model or resetting the tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

My deep_model function receives random calls from another function. Every time the deep_model function is called, I need the tf graph to be reset i.e., I don't want to add layers to the existing model. Please help.

```
def deep_model(L,N,X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test):
model=models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(N,activation='relu',input_shape=(4,)))
for i in range(1,L):
    model.add(layers.Dense(N,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=25,batch_size=50)
scores=model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
return scores[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Here is the respective [link from the TF Documentation.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reset_default_graph)